# Run Jest without code coverage constraint?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to inspect a single test so I run:

```
npm test alerts.actionCreators.test.js
```

The test passes, and then I get a huge printout of code coverage and then a failure for not meeting global standards. Can I skip this part of testing while I focus on the just whether the test passes or fails?

Answer (score 10):

I found a hack that mostly works: `--collectCoverageOnlyFrom ''`. With this the coverage table will be empty and take only about 5 lines.

Comment: In addition, I have just found another command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69443465/10102533) : --collectCoverage=false

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend adding a second test command to your [package.json](https://github.com/jaspenlind/node-ts-starter-template/blob/master/package.json#L54) :

```
{
  "test:watch": "jest --watch-all",
  ...
}
```

Jest will watch for changes in your tests/implementation and re-run the tests automatically. It should not cover the tests in watch mode.

It's good idea to run a coverage on your code from time to time. To make sure jest excluded code you don't want to cover, make sure to configure your [jest config](https://github.com/jaspenlind/node-ts-starter-template/blob/master/jest.config.js#L2) accordingly:

```
{
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/{!(*.d.ts),}.{ts,js,.tsx,.jsx}"],
  ...
}
```

More information about jest configuration can be found [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just add path to your file in `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` in you Jest configuration in `package.json`. See the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you have coverage thresholds set in your jest config file, then I recommend running:

```
jest --watch --coverageThreshold '{}'
```

This will ignore/override the thresholds so that `watch` doesn't report failing thresholds, since it only knows about coverage for the handful of files that you've changed. This also allows you to run a much smaller number of tests for each change, compared to `--watchAll`.

You can also pass that in the settings of the VS Code Jest extension.

[image]