# How to run Jest tests with coverage for one file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-scripts

I want to have coverage report for only one file that I am working on at the moment.

It is a bit overwhelming to have the full table of coverage for the whole application files and then search for the one I need.

What I tried was to run test for one file and add `--coverage`. But it shows coverage for all files:

**package.json**

```json
...
"test": "react-scripts test",
...
```

**My command**

`npm test my-component.test --coverage`

Is there an option that I can add to this command to show me only `my-component.tsx` coverage?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The solution is to add one small option `--collectCoverageFrom` to collect only for a certain file (i.e. component). This is based on [this post](https://joshtronic.com/2017/10/24/configuring-jest-to-show-code-coverage-for-all-of-your-files/)

**NPM version**
`npm test my-component.test -- --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/components/my-component/my-component.tsx`
*Notice an extra `--` before `--coverage...`. This needs to be passed for `npm` as following options provided will not be taken into consideration without it.*

**YARN version**
`yarn test my-component.test --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/components/my-component/my-component.tsx`

This will show coverage table only for `my-component.tsx`.

**NOTE**:

The path to `my-component.tsx` file needs to be relative to project root and exact. It cannot be relative as I did for `my-component.test`.

Comment: If someone wants to add multiple files, you can use this: `--collectCoverageFrom='["packages/**/index.js"]' --coverage` . Original Ref: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1932

Comment: Tried using the command from the above comment, but wouldn't work through the CLI. [According to the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--collectcoveragefromglob), looks like it no longer takes an array, just the glob.  `collectCoverageFrom="packages/**/index.js" --coverage` worked for me

Comment: If you add path/spec_file after the `--collectCoverageFrom...`, only that file will have the tests run. For example, `npm test my-component.test -- --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/components/my-component/my-component.tsx src/components/my-component/my-component.spec.tsx`.

Comment: That is correct. You can run also all tests and take only specific coverage info.

Comment: This worked for me: npm test -- [fileName] --coverage

Comment: Whit this command you are mentioning, you will run all of the tests and have coverage for all files. This answer is showcasing how to run tests from one test file and take coverage from one component file.

Comment: My coverage is alway 0 by running your above yarn command.

Comment: Check if you are targeting the correct file. It might happen that you misspelled file name. That happens to me all the time

Answer (score -4):

```
npm run test:coverage -- fileName.component.spec.ts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer